# Trouble deducing return type for wrapper of member functions

Tags: c++, c++14, wrapper, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a collection of methods with varying signatures which all need the same prefix and postfix code, so I'd like to wrap each of them up neatly.
I'm trying to formulate a C++14 variadic template for a generic wrapper to my member functions, and I hit trouble when deducing the return type. `auto` works, but I need the return type explicitly to provide a valid return value even if I catch an exception inside the wrapper when executing the wrappee.

So far I managed to deduce the return type for a plain wrapper function using `std::result_of` and I got correct behaviour for non static member functions using auto. I tried for two days now to make the `std::result_of` approach work for member functions, also tried a lot of variations of `decltype()` and `std::declval()`, but with no luck so far. I am running out of ideas on how to deduce the return type.

This is my working example

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int bar(char a, char b, char c) { return a + b * c; }


template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
typename std::result_of<Fn&(Args... )>::type 
wrapFunc(Fn f, Args... args) {
  //Do some prefix ops
  typename std::result_of<Fn&(Args... )>::type ret = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  //Do some suffix ops
  return ret;
}

class MemberWithAuto {
  private:
  public:
    MemberWithAuto() {};
    int foo(int i, int j) { return i + j;}

    template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
    auto wrapper(Fn f, Args... args) {
      //Do some prefix ops
      auto ret = (*this.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      //Do some suffix ops
      return ret;
    } 
};



int main() {

  std::cout << "FuncWrapper for foo with 1 + 2 returns "         << wrapFunc<decltype(foo)>(foo, 1, 2)      << std::endl;
  std::cout << "FuncWrapper for bar with 'a' + 'b' * 1  returns "  << wrapFunc<decltype(bar)>(bar, 'a','b', 1)  << std::endl;

  MemberWithAuto meau = MemberWithAuto();
  std::cout << "MemberFunction with Auto with 6 + 1 returns  "  << meau.wrapper(&MemberWithAuto::foo, 6, 1)  << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Both of these work well, but the wrapper method using auto doesn't get me the return type for later use. 
I tried lots of variations with `std::result_of` and `decltype()` with the following code, but I can't get it to compile correctly

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int bar(char a, char b, char c) { return a + b * c; }

class MemberWithDecl {
  private:
  public:
    MemberWithDecl() {};
    int foo(int i, int j) { return i + j;}

    template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
    typename std::result_of<Fn&(Args... )>::type wrapper(Fn f, Args... args) {
      //Do some prefix ops
      typename std::result_of<Fn&(Args... )>::type ret = (*this.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      //Do some suffix ops
      return ret;
    } 
};



int main() {
  MemberWithDecl medcl = MemberWithDecl();
  std::cout << "MemberFunction with declaration also works "  << medcl.wrapper(&MemberWithDecl::foo, 6, 1)  << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to find a solution where the signature of `Fn` with `Args...` is correctly recognized, because `auto` also successfully deduces the types. My type declaration does not seems to find a matching template though, no matter the variations I tried, I get

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MemberWithDecl::wrapper(int (MemberWithDecl::*)(int, int), int, int)’
```

If I leave the wrapper's return type to be auto and just try my declaration for the variable `ret` within, I get

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<int (MemberWithDecl::*&(int, int))(int, int)>’
       typename std::result_of<Fn&(Args... )>::type ret = (*this.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

After reading the standard, I think this means that result_of does not regard `Fn&(Args... )` to be well-formed, but I don't know how the correct form should look like.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: if you use `auto`, as function return type, without trailing return type, you're using C++14, not C++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `std::result_of`; you can simply write

```
  template <typename R, typename ... As1, typename ... As2>
  R wrapper (R(MemberWithDecl::*fn)(As1...), As2 ... args)
   { return (*this.*fn)(std::forward<As2>(args)...); }
```

If you really want to use `std::result_of`, you have to add a `MemberWithDecl` pointer (the type of `this`) as first argument.

```
  template <typename Fn, typename ... Args>
  typename std::result_of<Fn&(MemberWithDecl*, Args... )>::type
        wrapper (Fn f, Args ... args)
   {
     typename std::result_of<Fn&(MemberWithDecl*, Args... )>::type ret
        = (*this.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

     return ret;
   }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> but could you perhaps clarify why two separate parameter sets are needed in your first solution?

Two separate parameter sets aren't strictly required but this gives more flexibility.

Suppose you have a single set

```
  template <typename R, typename ... As>
  R wrapper (R(MemberWithDecl::*fn)(As...), As ... args)
   { return (*this.*fn)(std::forward<As>(args)...); }
```

and given

```
 long foo (long a, long b) { return a + b; }
```

suppose you call

```
 wrapFunc(foo, 1, 2)
```

Now the compiler has to deduce `As...` from `foo()` and from `1, 2`.

From `foo()`, the compiler deduce `As...` as `long, long`.

From `1, 2`, the compiler deduce `As...` as `int, int`.

So: compilation error because the compiler has a deduction conflict.

With a double set of types (`As1...` and `As2...`), the compiler deduce `As1...` as `long, long` and `As2...` as `int, int`. There isn't conflict so no compilation error.

And there isn't also problem calling `foo()` with `int` values because the `int`s are converted to `long`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both approaches work like a charm!

I think I got the std::result_of code, but could you perhaps clarify why two separate parameter sets are needed in your first solution?

The two sets are equal, which I can kind of prove too by changing the type in the wrapped function call to As1. So my guess is that the template can only be correctly filled in if the set of the member function pointers' parameter types and the set of parameter types I provide afterwards are distinct sets. Just because they happen to be equal, this does not allow a general reuse. Is this correct?

Comment: @Samuraiburger - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Very good explanation, it made the penny drop. And it is a nice and elegant solution. 

This works nicely when the compiler deduces the types, but I am still getting some grief when I need to provide the template parameter explicitly for disambiguation of overloaded member functions. I can easily get it to compile, but it does lead to linker errors I can't quite figure out. I'll experiment some more and open a new thread for that and cross reference the current one if I can't make anymore progress. Thanks again mate

Comment: <but I am still getting some grief when I need to provide the template parameter explicitly for disambiguation of overloaded member functions>

Turned out not be a templates fault. Seems related to a problem when linking as a shared library. So, original template problem wholly solved.